# Congruences involving central binomial coefficients

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

When $p$ is prime, one easily checks that ${2p \choose p} \equiv 2 \mod p$. Moreover, if $p \le 31$, we have even ${2p \choose p} \equiv 2 \mod p^2$. Is this true for all prime numbers? Is it easy to prove?
View the computation of of the first central binomial coefficients and of the ratios ${2n \choose n}-2$ by $n^2$ and by $n^3$

[image: computation of first binomial coefficients and ratios [2n \choose n]-2 by n^2 and by n^3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p>3$, this even holds $\pmod {p^3}$.

Proof:  [Wolstenholmes' Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WolstenholmesTheorem.html) tells us that $$\binom {2p-1}{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod {p^3}$$

But we have $$\binom {2p}p=2\times \binom {2p-1}{p-1}$$

by direct computation, so we are done.

Note $1$:  This strengthening of the desired claim is false for $p≤3$ but it is easy to check that the $p^2$ claim holds for those two primes.  Numerical evidence suggests that nothing special holds for $p^4$)

Note $2$:  As the OP has noted in a comment, a proof of Wolstenholmes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not knew this formulation. A proof is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem

Comment: Good link, I'll add that to the post.  Thanks!